# Eliminating auto zooming in mobile safari textarea widget?

Tags: ios, fonts, textarea, mobile-safari, zooming

I developed a web app for the iPhone which has a page with a textarea widget.  When I begin editing the contents of this textarea widget Safari zooms in and makes the text really, really big.  Now I can't see the document anymore, just a little postage stamp sized piece of it.

Are there any properties I can set which will keep mobile Safari from doint this?  I just want the textarea font to stay the same size when I edit its text.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

to your HTML header.

Comment: This is fairly user hostile. Please do NOT prevent user zooming, either through `maximum-scale=1.0` or `user-scalable=no`.

Comment: Though for websites I could agree, this is a valid tip for situations where you want to really prevent user zooming. I believe you cannot universally state that this is bad for UX. It depends on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set your textarea `font-size` to `16px` and have an `initial-scale` of `1.0`.

But if your app is not really designed for the iPhone, that is, if it’s essentially a normal web page that users *should* be able to scale, then you should probably just become okay with it. The worst thing to do to your users is show them 6pt text they can’t zoom, you know? Some of them won’t have perfect vision.

See also: [Apple's list of all Safari/iOS special meta tags](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html).